# Ember, extending multiple classes

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible in Ember to extend multiple classes?
For example:

```
 App.View1 = Ember.View.extend({ .. });

 App.View2 = Ember.View.extend({ .. });

 App.View3 = //here you want to extend View1 and View2 but without making View2 extending View1 or viceversa...
```

Comment: You might be looking for [Reopening Classes and Instances](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/).

Comment: I think this cannot solve the problem: with reopen you can add methods or attributes to an existing class; what I would like to do is to define inheritance from multiple classes

Comment: Fair point. What about Ember Mixins? [This article](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/) provides a good overview of the Ember Object. Apologies that I can't provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution :)

Comment: At the end I left ember in favor of meteor; I've not been able to easily obtain the desired result in any case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not extend or inherit from multiple classes. Ember only allows for single class inheritance. You are, instead, encouraged to use Mixins to "compose" your classes. In reality, using Mixins would probably make your application more modular to design and extend. And they are super easy to use in Ember.

You can find references here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Jeffrey Biles also did a [short & sweet screencast on this topic](https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/41-mixins).

There's also a "pro" [screencast he did on Mixins](http://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/41-mixins) should you be interested.